# Does having your knife out make you move faster? If not, what does?

Tags: battlefield-3

**Do you run faster with your knife out?** [I have tried to test this, but to no avail.]   I am aware you can get a small boost by jumping while running.  I am also aware having the sprint perk increases your speed.  I am looking for some documentation / proof that you actually do run faster with your knife out as appose to holding any other weapon and/or that the sprint perk is the only perk to stack with other squad members if they have the perk as well.

I heard through the 'grape-vine' that the squad-leader should have the sprint perk as the owner of the sprint perk gains a greater % of sprint speed than others in the squad and then squad members can just spawn on the squad leader once he/she reaches the objective. (I.E. = Squad leader gains 30% sprint increase for owning the perk, while everyone else gains 15% sprint increase - falsified data, just an example)

This actually matters on Metro, when it is a sprint to objective B.

[image: bf3 knife]

**EDIT:** I am still looking for proof.  Everything I have found has been inconclusive / speculation.  I do not want links of mere claims, Either from DICE or a reputable source!  I have already tried contacting EA via twitter - but yet to gain a reply.

Answer (score 4):

**Sprint Jumping** is the fastest method of getting from A to B, with the caveats that you become more visible and less capable of quickly killing a target thanks to the time it takes for your aim (the random spread, not your physical view) to settle down.

The part of the animation when you land from a sprinting jump moves your avatar faster forwards than the regular sprint speed, so continuously jumping while sprinting causes this part of the animation to repeat and over time this adds up to a significant bon

**For proof:** 
see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tooCrYL5E8) where two people run side by side, one sprinting, the other sprint jumping. Also just spend a couple of minutes with a friend to test will show you that sprint jumping and the sprint perk are the only way to increase sprint speed, no matter the weapon held or loadout equipped.

The sprint perk raises your speed by 10%, as seen in the [game data](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=spec) files themselves.

Comment: That video didn't show anything about running **knife** as appose to not running with the knife out... It only showed about the jumping trick.

Comment: Your question title is "How can I be the fastest sprinter in BF3". That video shows you how. Perhaps you should reword the question title?

If you want to know for sure that the knife doesn't make you sprint faster spend 30 seconds with a friend on a server testing it, rather than waiting a week for some 'proof' on here.

Answer (score 3):

I have no official word from DICE on this one, but running with a knife does **not** make you run faster (even if it seems like it does). Also, Squad perks spread evenly to the squad, so if the leader has 30% increased speed, so do the squadmates. On a further note, perks **do not** stack so the only way for you to get to the flag first is to take the most direct route and cut corners ever so perfectly.

Or, alternativley take one of those humvees at the spawn (I think they're on Metro) and drive right in there like a boss. (Joking)

Comment: hmmm.... @Emerica I am looking for some proof that it does / does not make you run faster. Also - on pc, on metro - there are no humvees. But, I could only imagine driving one in there **like a boss**.  +1 for your input, thank you.

Comment: Lol that second part was a joke, I thought there were vehicles outside the entrance parked in a blockade kind of thing. It's been awhile. Also there is a lot of speculation as to wether or not it makes you run faster, but the only way to really get evidence would be too stage a race, or ask DICE. Tweet them, I bet you'll get a response.

Comment: There are vehicles parked there but not accessible. lol

Comment: This might actually convince me to creating a twitter.  I've tried to avoid 'tweeting'... G+ and FB is the extent of it for me. lol

Answer (score 2):

No.

However, you do move slightly faster *when aiming* with certain guns.

E.g. moving while aiming with a pistol is faster than moving while aiming with a heavy assault rifle, or LMG.

It's a fairly mild effect.