# How does wielded weapon affect running speed?

Tags: battlefield-3

How does wielded weapon affect running speed? Will I run significantly faster for example with pistol than with RPG?

Comment: Simple answer "weapons do not effect weapon speed". There are plenty of resources around that mention this. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52240/how-can-i-be-the-fastest-sprinter-on-the-battlefield-3

Comment: @MennoGouw: yet this one says that PDWs "allow the player to move at full speed", as if other weapons didn't?

Comment: Simple physics. If the gun is heavy you will run slower.